# In which scenario or example is this function useful?

Tags: python

I found this exercise [Unexpected parsing](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54fdaa4a50f167b5c000005f/train/python), but maybe I do not understand it and for that reason I do not find it useful, since with the second code, the same thing is achieved (not for this exercise as stated, of course), if someone explains it would be of great help, thank you.
BTW Spoiler alert!

```
def get_status(is_busy):
    status = "busy" if is_busy else "available"
    return {"status": status}

get_status(True)["status"]


def get_status(is_busy):
    status = "busy" if is_busy else "available"
    return status

get_status(True)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. The first function returns dict, the second function returns a string, so the statement that "the same thing is achieved" is wrong

Comment: If the status cannot be expressed with a single value, then returning some structure that can contain multiple values can be useful.

Comment: Judging by the exercise's tests, the first version is expected.

Comment: We don't know why this API would want to return one thing and not another. All we know is that the test requires that the function return something who's `__getitem__` returns certain values. Whether this is a good thing depends on the design of the project. Suppose the intent is to return JSON to a client application - this would be a good way to do it.

Comment: For the purposes of the exercise, the answers are not the same, in the explanation I said it. The point is that in both cases, the result is a single word "busy" or "available", I don't understand why you would need to use (in the real world) a `dict` to do that.

Comment: I think tdelaney answer is what resembles what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, I extended the exercise a little, which allowed me to visualize how it could be used, and of course I found that with the first case, you can also handle the argument as such of the function, and then also the value of a `dict`depending on that first argument (I obviously hadn't thought of that before):

```
def get_status(is_busy):
    status_a = 'a' if is_busy else 'b'
    status_b = 'c' if is_busy else 'd'
    return {'1': status_a , '2': status_b}

get_status(True)['2']
# 'c'
get_status(False)['1']
# 'b'
```